# Elasticsearch bool query sort by date if status is true

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I have a JSON file like as follows in an Elasticsearch index. I need to sort data if the advertisement does not expire and status is true, and then sort them as desc. How can I achieve this?

I tried using end_date sort, but it did not work. Also I need to show all expired data which end_date are expired.

```
 advertisement = [
   {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "status": True,
        "start_date": "2020-08-09",
        "end_date": "2020-09-09",
    },
   {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test2",
        "status": False,
        "start_date": "2020-08-09",
        "end_date": "2020-08-09",
    }]
```

This is my elastic search method.

```
def elastic_search(category=None):
    client = Elasticsearch(host="localhost", port=9200)
    query_all = {
        'size': 10000,
        'query': {
            "bool": {
                "filter": [
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "name": "test"
                        }
                    }]
               },
        },
        "sort": [
        {
            "end_date": {
                "type": "date",
                "order": 'desc'
            }
        }
    ]
    }
    resp = client.search(
        index="my-index",
        body=query_all
        )
    return resp
```

This is my es response

http://localhost:9200/my-index/_search

```
   {
   "took":96,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{
      "total":5,
      "successful":5,
      "skipped":0,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{
      "total":36,
      "max_score":1.0,
      "hits":[
         {
            "_index":"my-index",
            "_type":"doc",
            "_id":"52",
            "_score":1.0,
            "_source":{
               "id": 1,
               "name": "test",
               "status": True,
               "start_date": "2020-08-09",
               "end_date": "2020-09-09",
            }
         },
         {
            "_index":"my-index",
            "_type":"doc",
            "_id":"60",
            "_score":1.0,
            "_source":{
               "id": 1,
               "name": "English test",
               "status": True,
               "start_date": "2020-08-09",
               "end_date": "2020-09-09",
            }
         },
         {
            "_index":"my-index",
            "_type":"doc",
            "_id":"40",
            "_score":1.0,
            "_source":{
               "id": 1,
               "name": "Designw test",
               "status": false,
               "start_date": "2020-08-09",
               "end_date": "2020-09-09",
            }
         },
         {
            "_index":"my-index",
            "_type":"doc",
            "_id":"41",
            "_score":1.0,
            "_source":{
               "id": 1,
               "name": "Designw New",
               "status": false,
               "start_date": "2020-08-09",
               "end_date": "2020-09-09",
            }
         },
         {
            "_index":"my-index",
            "_type":"doc",
            "_id":"59",
            "_score":1.0,
            "_source":{
               "id": 1,
               "name": "Designw New",
               "status": false,
               "start_date": "2020-08-09",
               "end_date": "2020-09-09",
            }
         },
         {
            "_index":"my-index",
            "_type":"doc",
            "_id":"62",
            "_score":1.0,
            "_source":{
               "id": 1,
               "name": "Designw New",
               "status": false,
               "start_date": "2020-08-09",
               "end_date": "2020-09-09",
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This is my mapping http://localhost:9200/my-index/_mapping response.

```
"my-index":{
      "mappings":{
         "_doc":{
            "properties":{
               "address":{
                  "properties":{
                     "name":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "fields":{
                           "keyword":{
                              "type":"keyword",
                              "ignore_above":256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "start_date":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "fields":{
                           "keyword":{
                              "type":"keyword",
                              "ignore_above":256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "end_date":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "fields":{
                           "keyword":{
                              "type":"keyword",
                              "ignore_above":256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "id":{
                        "type":"long"
                     },
                     "status":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "fields":{
                           "keyword":{
                              "type":"keyword",
                              "ignore_above":256
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What's your mapping?

Comment: Need to sort data by not expire date and sort them

Comment: Come again. What's your index *mapping*? `GET my-index/_mapping`

Comment: yes get i ma confuse ? what are you asking? can you please explain little more . It is GET my-index/_mapping

Comment: We need to see your mapping in order to help you. Read this though if you're not familiar with what I'm talking about: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

Comment: all date are date field, status in boolean , name in text() and id in integer etc. Thanks for asking please help.

Comment: Again, I don't need a generic description of your mapping. I need you to copy & paste the response of `http://localhost:9200/my-index/_mapping`

Comment: @joe I added my es response. Thanks for query. i added http://localhost:9200/my-index/_mapping  response.

Comment: It's not. It's the _search response, not _mapping.

Comment: @joe i am bit confuse i added all response of my http://localhost:9200/my-index/_search response. Thanks for response.

Comment: Can you please suggest some example or valuable link to do this task please

Comment: joy - in your recent comment to @joe, you mention that you added "all response of my localhost:9200/my-index/_search response". Joe is looking for **_mapping** response, not the **_search** response that you provided. Please try again to copy & paste the response of `http://localhost:9200/my-index/_mapping`.

Comment: Thanks all for suggestion and negative voting. @joe i have added mapping response. Please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things regarding the mapping:

1. There's an `address` field there that's not found in your actual documents. Remove it.
2. Your dates should be mapped correctly using the [`date`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html) datatype.

A correct mapping would look like this:

```
{
  "properties":{
    "end_date":{
      "type":"date",
      "format":"yyyy-MM-dd"
    },
    "start_date":{
      "type":"date",
      "format":"yyyy-MM-dd"
    },
    //...other properties
  }
}
```

Once you get the mapping right, this query looks for all non-expired ads w/ a true status and sorts by the longest running:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "end_date": {
              "gt": "now"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "status": {
              "value": true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "end_date": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Alternatively, if you're looking for the expired ones, change `gt` to `lt` which stands for [less-than](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#ranges-on-dates).